# Link with framework on macOS Mojave

Tags: linker, frameworks, linker-errors, macos-mojave

Prior to the update to Mojave, my projects (which I build on the command line) linked perfectly fine with the frameworks I installed in /Library/Frameworks. Now, it seems that this path is no longer searched by the linker (include files within the frameworks are also not searched).

I’m aware I can specify the include and framework paths with -I and -F, respectively, but I thought this was the canonical way to link with an installed framework on macOS. Should I be doing this differently now?

Comment: Got the same issue, ended up exporting LIBRARY_PATH in my bash_profile. Would love to know why this is necessary all of a sudden.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your exact build environment, but, following [this comment on neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/9050#issuecomment-424417456), it seems like macOS 10.14 isn't installing all headers in the expected locations anymore.

After installing the package mentioned in the comment above, things worked fine again !

Edit: the actual way to install the headers (as found in abovementioned comment):

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

This is not triggered automatically during or after the update.